# Program to set a video as a wallpaper on Windows?

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-7, video, wallpaper

Today I am looking for a program to set a video as my wallpaper on Windows 7 and Windows XP.

I need it to be **free**. If it costs, I am not looking to spend over $20. Is there a program on Windows 7 and compatible with Windows XP that can do this?

I have tried doing this with [VLC](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18167/set-a-video-as-your-desktop-wallpaper-with-vlc/) player, but didn't have DirectX Video Output on the drop-down list. I also tried [DreamScene](http://www.door2windows.com/dreamscene-activator-activate-dreamscene-in-all-editions-of-windows-7-vista/). Didn't work and only works/is supported on Windows Vista and 7. I did try it on Windows 7 but didn't work.

Nice to haves are.....

- Free
- Is compatible and can run on both Windows Xp and Windows 7
- Portable (?) if possible

Comment: You can use VLC.

Comment: @AndréDaniel- Technically I already did that but in the drop down options it seems that it was gone- the DirectX Video Output.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling DirectX ?

Comment: @AndréDaniel- I don't know how to do that. I would have assumed it was pre-installed but it wasn't for mine (?)

Comment: Yeah it's normally preinstalled and updated through Windows Update, but try [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35) anyway, then reboot your computer and see if DX video output works again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Stardock DeskScapes](http://www.stardock.com/products/deskscapes/):

- 10 USD (one-month trial)
- Use your images and videos as the desktop wallpaper
- Windows 8.1/8/7
- Multi-monitor support

> Stardock DeskScapes is a program that allows users to have animated
>   wallpaper on their Windows Vista desktop.  It supports playing video
>   as animated wallpaper, dynamically generated content as animated
>   wallpaper, and more.
>
> DeskScapes supports the new .Dream format.  The .Dream format has been
>   specifically designed to contain content intended to be used as
>   animated wallpaper (making it much easier to find on the net than
>   looking for video files).  The .Dream format supports triggers,
>   dynamic content, MPEG video, WMV video, and author information.

[image]

Comment: It is a good application. Am using it.